# How to choose compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion for a given device?

Tags: android, version

My device is installing Android 4.3. When I try to install an Android app on that device through Android Studio, I got compatible "minSdk (API 18) > deviceSdk(API 1)". I wander how to choose compatible version for that device. Below is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android { compileSdkVersion 23 buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.yzzhao.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}
```

Comment: Your targetSDK version must be at least 20.

Answer (score 3):

Since your Android phone version is Android 4.3(API level 18), you can use compileSdkVersion 18 for actual accurate result. buildToolsVersion should be 18.0.1 or higher

Comment: Below is my build.gradle file and I got compatible "minSdk (API 18) > deviceSdk(API 1)".

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yzzhao.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    
}

Answer (score 0):

If you're using android studio /Go to file -> Project Structure->application.
Then set your compile sdk version in properties tab and min/target sdk version in flavours tab.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out that the problem is because the device is not authorised by my computer. After reset enable USB debug, it works.

Answer (score -1):

My device is installing Android 4.3. When I try to install an Android app on that device through Android Studio, I got compatible "minSdk (API 18) > deviceSdk(API 1)". I wander how to choose compatible version for that device. Below is my build.gradle file:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.yzzhao.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

}

Comment: Set your minSdkVersion to 17 or lower then. please recheck whether your device is having Android 4.3. One more thing, Rather than posting this as answer, you could have edited your question.

Comment: I got the same error when change minSdkVersion to 17. The error became to minSdk (API 17) > deviceSdk(API 1). My device is 4.3 version.